# How to combine two asp.net mvc websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, iis-7.5, structure

For a formbuilder project I am currently working on I want to be able to add it to different websites without the need to duplicate code.
Each website has a different page structure and layout. But all websites must be able to log in to the same formbuilder project.
The domain name for each website is different.

This is my current Solution layout:

Solution 1
website http://www.domain1.com

- DAL.dll (Formbuilder data access)
- Business.dll (Formbuilder logic)
- Web (contains website and formbuilder controllers/views)

Solution 2
website http://www.anotherdomain.com

- DAL.dll (Formbuilder data access)
- Business.dll (Formbuilder logic)
- Web (contains website and formbuilder controllers/views)

The problem with this solution layout is that for each website I add the same formbuilder controllers and views. When I have to change the formbuilder I need to make the same change on each website. Is there a way to add the formbuilder as one module to my websites?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using MVC Areas to separate the code within the same website project.

[Getting Started With Areas in MVC5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-area-in-mvc-5/)

Comment: That way I would still have the the same formbuilder code on multiple websites. So if I need to change something then I would still need to make the same change in different solutions